# Firebase database not show error in console when I refresh the page

Tags: python, reactjs, firebase

Hi I am creating users in my users database in firestore database, i HAVE UPDATED THE RULES OF UPDATE AND DELETE of the firestore security but my console show the error of updating document When i open my browser it fetch all data but when I refresh the page it show all messages of edit , delete and with updating errors in my console neither i delete user nor i add user.
My firebase initialization file.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';
const firebaseConfig = {

  apiKey: "AIzaSyB9rcEN0cx3zeiMmXd1wIHi9tnUUQV9YSE",

  authDomain: "usersrolles.firebaseapp.com",

  projectId: "usersrolles",

  storageBucket: "usersrolles.appspot.com",

  messagingSenderId: "1035496456432",

  appId: "1:1035496456432:web:781d947a76f8e91f420235"


};


// Initialize Firebase

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth= getAuth()
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

My Login.jsx file.

```
import './login.scss'
import { auth,app,db} from '../../firebase'
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, query, where, getDocs,doc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
// Create two users manually


const Login = () => {

      const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]); // initialize the state to an empty array
      const usersRef = collection(db, 'users');
    
      // Get all user documents from Firestore when the component mounts
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUsers = async () => {
          try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(usersRef);
            const users = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
            setUsersList(users);
            console.log('All users:', users);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error getting users:', error);
          }
        };
        fetchUsers();
      }, []);
    
      // Update the Firestore collection with the new list of users
      const updateFirestore = async () => {
        try {
          const docRef = doc(db, 'users', 'user-list');
          await updateDoc(docRef, { users: usersList });
          console.log('User list updated!');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error updating user list: ', error);
        }
      };
    
      // Add a new user to the list and update the Firestore collection
      useEffect(() => {
        const newUserName = 'Usama';
        const newUserEmail = 'usama@example.com';
        const existingUser = usersList.find(user => user.email === newUserEmail);
        if (existingUser) {
          console.log('User of same email already exists!');
        } else {
          const newUsersList = [...usersList, { name: newUserName, email: 
          newUserEmail }];
          setUsersList(newUsersList);
          updateFirestore();
          console.log('New user added!');
        }
      }, [usersList]);
    
      // Delete a user from the list and update the Firestore collection
      useEffect(() => {
        const userToDelete = { name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com' };
        const existingUser = usersList.find(user => user.email === userToDelete.email);
        if (existingUser) {
          const newUsersList = usersList.filter(user => user.email !== userToDelete.email);
          setUsersList(newUsersList);
          updateFirestore();
          console.log('User deleted!');
        } else {
          console.log('User does not exist!');
        }
      }, [usersList]);
    
      // Count the number of users in the list and display it in the console
      useEffect(() => {
        const userCount = usersList.length;
        console.log(`There are ${userCount} users in the list.`);
      }, [usersList]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          {/*Render the list of users*/}
          {usersList.map(user => (
            <div key={user.email}>
              <p>Name: {user.name}</p>
              <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Login;
```

Please help to find out the error, I want when I refresh the page there is no such error and when I add or delete the user console will show specific message according to the action.
[image]